# Is it correct to solve a recurrence equation if the heredity that only works from a certain rank?

Tags: calculus, logic, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

Sorry my title maybe does not describe my question perfectly I had some troubles to formulate it in a short way. Here is an example. I was trying to solve the recurrence equation $T(n) = 4*T(⌊n/2⌋)+cn$ ( c being a constant ). I made the hypothesis of $T(n) = θ(n²)$  I want to show that this is true using the substitution method. I proceed separately for Ω and O, starting with Ω, I supposed we have $T(m) >= c'm²$ for any m < n and for c' a constant > 0 then I wanted to prove it for n so I did this :
$T(m) >= 4c'(⌊n/2⌋)²+cn >= 4c'((n-1)²/2))+cn = 4c'((n²-2n+1)/2)+cn = (4c'n²-8c'n +4c')/2+cn = 2c'n²-4c'n+2c'+cn = 2c'n²-4c'n+2c'+cn >= c'n²$ But the last inequality work only from a certain rank n ( at least I guess it work from a certain rank n, don't hesitate to tell me if this is wrong, I justify it by saying that -4c1n is o(n²) so it will be "annulated" by one of the c'n² in the long term ) but if I think to it, this does mean that the recurrence heredity is only true from a certain rank, it means that even if you prove the base's cases  from let's say 1 to a certain x, maybe x is before the first p such $(T(p) <= c'p²) ⇒  T(p*2) <= c'(p*2)²$, do you see what I mean ?

Comment: I haven't read the question in detail. If you are interested in asymptotic behavior (big-O or big-Theta) then all you need is an argument that works from some $n$ on. What happens at the start is irrelevant.

Comment: Sure but my question is about when you try to show that something is for instance  θ(n²) using a recurrence, To prove that f(n) = θ(g(n)) using substitution you do a recurrence, you have to prove 2 things :The first is the base case, you prove that the inequality is true at least for first values, then you prove induction hypothesis but what if induction itself work only starting from a given rank, that rank could be higher than the one until which you did your base case proof, do you see what I mean ?

Comment: And then the recurrence itself would stop to works, you would have for instance proven that ( lets note P(n) the fact that $c1*n²<= T(n) <= c2*n² )$ you have P(1), P(2), P(3) by the hand and that $P(n) => P(n+1)$ but this induction working only if n > = 250, in this case your proof dont work, right ? So for instance, does my proof work please ?

Comment: Clearly you have to start the induction from a value where you know correctness by some other means. If you check $n=1,2,3$ by hand and your induction works only for $n > 250$ you have proved nothing. But if you check the case $n=300$ (say) by hand then you can ignore all the smaller values. This is just common sense. There's no "rule" to master.